# Git error: error: open("global.css"): Permission denied

Tags: html, css, git, github

I try staging files and they all give me a weird error. Below is the command and output from the terminal:

```
$ git add --ignore-errors .
error: open("global.css"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file global.css
error: open("index.html"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file index.html
error: open("json/projects.json"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file json/projects.json
error: open("projects.html"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file projects.html
error: open("src/projects.js"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file src/projects.js
```

I closed out of Sublime and any tabs I was using to view the HTML. I made the repo two days ago and was staging and committing files with no problems.

Comment: what about `git add --ignore-errors --force .` ??

Comment: same result as before